# Implementing CORS in Angular+ Node

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, express, cors

I have a impolemented frontend in Node+Angular js and backend is running in Jetty exposing REST service.I want to send REST rquest from FE(Angular) to backend.when I am passing the complete URL  to $http.get it works fine.However I want to mak it a configurable value so that any change in the URL/Port will not require me to change elsewhere apart from the configuration.Currently I am passing it as `$http.post("http://localhost:8080/test/login/doStuff",dataObj)`
However I want to pass it as `$http.post("/test/login/doStuff",dataObj)` and automatically it should append http://localhost:8080.Can someone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CORS is used to enable the communication trust between two different hosts. For example if the front end and back-end hosted in two different servers (not in the same domain) requires CORS to communicate in between.
However, in your case, I do not see a valid case except they deployed apart as explained.
A web app always can communicate using relative paths as long as they are hosted in the same server. 
If the app hosted inside `/myApp` folder, it can access other resources using `/myApp/other-web-folders`.
If you want to communicate outside domain, you always have to do it with the full url. Hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand it. i want to make the url configurable.Is there any way that If I specify a relative url in the angular method then the other domain url will get appended?

Comment: You can devise a mechanism like this. Always seperate the URL to two parts. The `host` and the `path`. You can change the host if it requires to load from a separate domain accordingly. This is just a suggestion. However, you don't have to do anything at the Angular level to enable CORS as its happen at the web server level.

Answer (score 0):

> You can store the hostname in another variable and concat that with
>   url

```
let host = "http://localhost:8080"

$http.post(host + "/test/login/doStuff", dataObj)
```